# Use wildcard query on dataset with models in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, wildcard

I have a series of tables that are named `{YYYYMM}_{id}` and I have ML models that are named `{groupid}_cost_model`. I'm attempting to collate some data across all the tables using the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `mydataset.20*`
```

The problem I'm having is that I have a model named `200_cost_model` and it causes the following error:

```
Wildcard table over non partitioning tables and field based partitioning tables is not yet supported, first normal table myproject:mydataset.200_cost_model, first column table myproject:mydataset.202001_4544248676.
```

Is there a way to filter out the models from wildcard queries or am I stuck joining all the tables together?

Answer (score 0):

When using [Wildcard tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/wildcard-table-reference) you can use psuedo column to filter results:

> Queries with wildcard tables support the _TABLE_SUFFIX pseudo column
> in the WHERE clause. This column contains the values matched by the
> wildcard character, so that queries can filter which tables are
> accessed. For example, the following WHERE clauses use comparison
> operators to filter the matched tables

I have tested on my side, although only on standard freshly created tables, that it should work for example like that:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  `mydataset.20*`
WHERE
    _TABLE_SUFFIX like '%cost_model' ;
```

As well to check all possible `_TABLE_SUFFIX` choices it work to me like this:

```
select  DISTINCT   _TABLE_SUFFIX as suffix from  `mydataset.20*`
```

but I am not sure, if this will work in your situation.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor No, this solution does not fix the error

Comment: @Woody1193 - you got the same effect? exactly the same error?

Comment: @vitooh Yes, I got the exact same error.